# Not able to format a simple time span field in

Tags: c#, time, formatting

I have this code where I am trying to calculate the difference between two date times. Here is my code:

```
int counter = 0;
foreach (EDIFile TimeDiff in FilesInfo)
{
    if (FilesInfo[counter].outfileDateTime != DateTime.MinValue && FilesInfo[counter].infileDateTime != DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        FilesInfo[counter].timeDiff = TimeDiff.outfileDateTime - TimeDiff.infileDateTime;
    }
    counter++;
}
```

The thing I need to know is the syntax to show the resulting time span timeDiff in just minutes and seconds. I've done lots of searches and all of the Microsoft pages on the subject are garbage. Can someone please help? Thanks in advance for any help rendered.

Comment: `TimeSpan` struct would allow you to subtract two datetimes.

Comment: What do you want to happen if there's a span which is more than an hour? (I disagree with your view that the MS pages are "garbage" btw - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632(v=vs.110).aspx is a pretty good starting point.

Comment: Something like: `Console.WriteLine($"{(int)diff.TotalMinutes}:{diff.Seconds}");`

Comment: I also would point you to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `FilesInfo[counter].timeDiff` is a `TimeSpan`, you can combine the `TotalMinutes` property with the `Seconds` property:

```
var dt1 = DateTime.Parse("2016-1-1 11:46:33");
var dt2 = DateTime.Parse("2016-1-2 1:24:34");
var ts = dt2 - dt1;
Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1:00}", Math.Floor(ts.TotalMinutes), ts.Seconds);

> 818:01
```